# How to append with logic bricks?

Tags: game-engine

Basically I want to make a game where a user can add their own levels by making a blend file with an object in called a certain thing, so for example you would have to call the level "Object.001" or something for it to work. Then when you start the level, it plays that level. And no I do NOT want to make it just open the blend file, because then I would have to make a template but people would just steal the template and use it for themselves and claim it.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, I will just mention that the biggest issue in the current game market is not theft, it is the opposite: trying to get people to play your game out of the thousands of others.

My suggestion is to:

- Provide a basic template to everyone (so who would steal it?)
- Provide good documentation on what objects you can add that do what.

OR
Take a completely alternate approach, such as having a blend file called 'LevelParts.blend' with groups of objects people can append to their custom levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LibLoad to load scenes from a file and merge all objects into the current scene.